# Data turns on automatically

Tags: android-versions

I am using lenovo k3 note. I recently updated to android 6.0 marshmallow.  Whenever I turn on the phone secondary SIM data turns on automatically.

Help me to solve this issue friends???

Answer (score -2):

I think that this kind of problem can be caused by some sorts of applications that have access or permission to enable your mobile data,I know that Facebook,Whatsapp & maybe every single social media app does not have that kind of permission.I know that samsung got a disabling option that turns off mobile data for good.that's all I know about that buddy

Comment: This does not qualify as an answer. You seem to think this is a free-for-all discussion. Answers here need to be backed up by facts, and be formulated professionally.

Comment: FACTS NOT THOUGHTS!